# Default render based on conditions

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm designing a basic login/sign up interface. Login and Signup UIs reside in their own components, and each contain a link to each other (using `<Link to>` in case user already has an account when signup is displayed, or wants to create an account when login is displayed).

My structure is as follows:

### index.tsx

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MemoryRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} >
        <Route path="signup" element={<Signup />} />
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes >
  </MemoryRouter >,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

### App.tsx

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserControl />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

### UserControl.tsx

```
function UserControl() {
///snip unrelated code

    if (!isLoggedIn && !userHasNeverLoggedInBefore) {
        return (<Signup />)
    } else if (!isLoggedIn) {
        return (<Login />)
    } else {
        return (<Functionality />
        )
    }
}
```

When opening '/', I want the decide whether to display Login, Signup or Functionality. I also want links in Login and Signup to each other.

With my current approach, I see the UI twice - I'm assuming one comes from the `<UserControl>` in App.tsx, and the other from the `<Outlet>`. How can I conditionally render it just once?

I'm using React Router 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering them twice. I suggest using a redirect in `UserControl` to push the user to the correct route rendering the correct `Login` or `Signup` component.

Example:

```
function UserControl() {
  // ... snip unrelated code

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <Navigate
        to={userHasNeverLoggedInBefore ? "/login" : "/signup"}
        replace
      />
    );
  }
  return <Functionality />;
}
```

### Update

> This seems to render the first component correctly, however now the
> links between login and sign up are broken (clicking does nothing).
> For context, this is how I set up links in the component : `<Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link>` and similarly for the sign up component.

I think the issue here is that you are creating a quasi-AuthWrapper component that is redirecting to a route it is rendering as a child. When testing your code with my solution it turned into an infinite render loop. Totally not ideal.

What I suggest then is to convert `UserControl` into a full-blown AuthWrapper component.

1. Replace `<Functionality />` with the `<Outlet />` component.

   ```
   function UserControl() {
     // ... snip unrelated code

     if (!isLoggedIn) {
       return (
         <Navigate
           to={userHasNeverLoggedInBefore ? "/login" : "/signup"}
           replace
         />
       );
     }
     return <Outlet />;
   }
   ```
2. Move the routes into `App`. Use the `UserControl` component as a layout component to protect a route rendering `<Functionality />`. Move the login and signup routes ***out*** of the auth wrapper.

   ```
   function App() {
     return (
       <div className="App">
         <Routes>
           <Route element={<UserControl />}>
             <Route path="/" element={<Functionality />} />
           </Route>
           <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
           <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
         </Routes>
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

[image: Edit default-render-based-on-conditions]

Comment: This seems to render the first component correctly, however now the links between login and sign up are broken (clicking does nothing).
For context, this is how I set up links in the component :

<Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link>

and similarly for the sign up component.

Comment: @user3073511 Ok, let me stand up a codesandbox and test this out.

Comment: @user3073511 I've updated my answer to include finding during testing solution, and a suggested refactor. Please check it out.

Comment: I tried it out - I can now switch between the login/signup components via the link, thanks. One thing that I can't figure out yet is how to display the <Functionality> component once the user logs in (or has logged in in the past). Assuming I can set the value of `isLoggedIn` correctly, how do I render <Functionality>? Right now I see the Signup page always